# Repairing invalid HTML with Nokogiri (removing invalid tags)

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to tidy some retrieved HTML using the [tidy-ext gem](https://github.com/carld/tidy). However, it fails when the HTML is quite broken, so I'm trying to repair the HTML using Nokogiri first:

```
repaired_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(a.raw_html).to_html
```

It seems to do a nice job but lately I encountered a sample where people inserted FBML markup into the HTML document such as `<fb:like>` which is somehow preserved by Nokogiri although being invalid. Tidy then says `Error: <fb:like> is not recognized!` which is understandable.

I'm wondering if there are any more options like *strict* or something which forces Nokogiri only to include valid HTML tags and omit everything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse HTML using Nokogiri's XML parser, which is strict by default but that only helps a little, because it will still do fixups so the HTML/XML is marginally correct. By adjusting the flags you can pass to the parser you can make Nokogiri even more rigid so it will refuse to return an invalid document. Nokogiri is not a sanitizer or a white-list for desired tags. Check out [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) and [Sanitize](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize) for that functionality.

If your HTML content is in a variable called `html`, and you do:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(html)
```

then check `doc.errors` afterwards to see if you had errors. Nokogiri will attempt to fix them, but anything that generated an error will be flagged there.

For instance:

```
Nokogiri::XML('<fb:like></fb:like>').errors
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Namespace prefix fb on like is not defined>]
```

Nokogiri will attempt to fix up the HTML:

```
Nokogiri::XML('<fb:like></fb:like>').to_xml
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<like/>\n"
```

but it only corrects it to the point of removing the unknown namespace on the tag.

If you want to strip those nodes:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<fb:like></fb:like>')
doc.search('like').each{ |n| n.remove }
doc.to_xml => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't do the trick. I guess a different parsing model is not the solution as XML allows even more tags (basicly whatever comes to mind...) and will not be stricter when filtering out things that are not allowed. - The errors are an interesting source, however telling me that `Entity 'nbsp' not defined` which I think is strange...

Comment: Related: (How can you add line breaks in these comments?!) parsing HTML (like I posted above) yields the error `Tag fb:like invalid` which is a good thing as Nokogiri seems to understand that there is something wrong. But how to tell it to fix it?

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't "fix it". It gives you the tools to fix it. Tell it to find and strip the tags like the last example in my answer. It works whether you've parsed the content in XML or HTML mode. If you want to see the document as HTML use `doc.to_html`.

Comment: Well, it does seem to fix it "a little". As you wrote it will remove the invalid prefix `fb` thus creating another invalid tag `like` which it keeps in the document. To me this is bug. Either it should repair the document to try to make it valid (ie. parsing the resulting document again should not yield errors) or it should not alter it at all. What seems to happen is sort or crap-repair in my opinion. How am I supposed to clean all invalid tags? Iterating errors, scanning string error messages and removing nodes per hand?

Comment: It isn't Nokogiri's job to fix bad markup. Many parsers would simply refuse to parse and you'd have nothing to work with. To be friendly and useful they chose to have Nokogiri give you the choice of getting something to work with, though it is marginally correct or to get nothing. It can't decide what is a cleaned up document, only you can so it gives you something to start with and you go from there. It's not a big deal and is something that several gems will do for you if you don't know how. The `tidy` gem isn't a parser, and the code it's based on is showing its age.

Comment: "`Entity 'nbsp' not defined`" is probably because you are parsing a HTML document in XML mode. If I remember right, XML doesn't support named entities, or maybe they had to be in a `CDATA[[` block.