# Displaying invalid HTML in layout

Tags: html, ruby, xml, latexml

Not sure how to tag this question. I have a database of XHTML documents that are converted by LaTeXMLpost; however, saying that they have validation issues is an understatement. I need to show them inside a browser. However, tag autoclosing due to invalid markup messes up my structure.

A minimal example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" style="background-color:pink">
      <!-- yield -->

      <section >
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>
              <p>
                First
                <li>
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      Second
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
        Next
      </section>

      <!-- end yield -->
    </div><!-- end content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytFXd/2/)

Everything outside  comments is layout; inside it is the loaded document. If things were taken at face value, everything should be pink, right?

The problem is, "Next" gets booted outside the `#content`. Even though it is valid XML, it does not conform to HTML/XHTML DTD (or whatever passes for DTD in HTML5), so it gets mangled.

The question is: *How can I protect my layout against invalid markup inside it?* Can I do something to the content to normalise it? I'm loading it into Nokogiri before displaying, but I still end up in this mess anyway (since the XML isn't malformed, I suppose, Nokogiri doesn't do anything about it).

I don't care if it's displayed nicely or not, all I care now is that it remains safely contained (otherwise I have trouble with manipulating it, attaching events, styling, and pretty much everything else).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Nokogiri it has some built-in functionality for fixing invalid mark-up.

Related question : [Repairing invalid HTML with Nokogiri (removing invalid tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557510/repairing-invalid-html-with-nokogiri-removing-invalid-tags)

Comment: I *am* using Nokogiri. However, as I said above - the XML is well-formed, there are no unknown or crossed tags... but it is being mangled by the browser's HTML assumptions of where one should put a closing tag. Unfortunately, there is nothing in the linked question that is remotely relevant, as it concerns invalid tags. :(

Comment: How about using something like https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize still based on nokogiri but the transformers look useful. One way would be to write such logic that checks whether the current node parent is valid from a validator pov if not remove it.

Worse case solution : just flatten the whole thing with something like   document.text or document.clean